# log4j and websphere JVM custom properties

Tags: log4j, websphere

I just want to know how the log4j is able to access the websphere custom properties.

When we add something like this  in log4j.xml, it is mapped to log.level properties in the web sphere server.

How is it being mapped?

Answer (score 0):

The WebSphere enviornment variables cannot be accessed directly by log4j.xml or log4j.properties.

THe standard trick that people do is to create JVM Custom properties that reference the WebSphere environment variables.

These JVM Custom properties are available like any other System Property to the log4j.xml or log4j.properties.

HTH
Manglu